# Finding the lowest common value in repeating sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

Assume I have `N` sequences of ones and zeros. Each sequence repeats every `p` terms. I want to find the minimum position where all sequences evaluate to "1"

Here is an example set of sequences for $N = 3$ and $p = \{2, 3, 5\}$:

$$
\begin{align}
a_1 & = \{1, 0, 1, 0, ...\} \\
a_2 & = \{0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, ...\} \\
a_3 & = \{0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1,...\} \\
\end{align}
$$

Observing that $14 = 0\ mod\ 2$ and $14 = 2\ mod\ 3$ and $14 = 4\ mod\ 5$ all of which correspond to "1"s in the above sequence we can verify that 14 is a possible solution. By simply extending the pattern we can find that the 14th element is indeed the first to yield "1" for each sequence.

I attempted to solve this analytically by [converting the patterns into closed form equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/441408/7290); however this seems impractical once `N` or `p` become non-trivial. I may be wrong but I can't find a good method for solving large systems of complex equation over integers.

For my problem it can be assume that all sequence repeat sizes (`p`) are coprime. It can also be assumed that $100 < N < p < 1000$. That is, I could be looking at 100 to 1000 sequences that have patterns that repeat every 1000 terms. Each pattern will have approximately $p/2$ "1"s. Therefor, trying to brute force the solution by solving every set of congruencies is not efficient.

Is there a general name for this type of problem? What are some efficient ways of finding the lowest common term position?

Comment: I suspect this is a computationally infeasible ("NP-complete") problem. If you have access to a copy of Garey & Johnson, have a look to see whether this problem is listed there.

Comment: Related (not identical) problem: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/257161/solutions-to-simultaneous-excluded-congruences

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my view this problem is hopeless in terms of computing an actual answer.  If you let $p_i$ be an index where  $a_i$ is 1 ($1\le p_i\le p$), and you do this for all $i$ ($1\le i\le N$), then you can solve this specific problem with the [CRT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem).  However there are over $50^N$ such problems that you are minimizing over, and the function you're trying to minimize is not particularly natural here, since $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ has no innate order, and you need to project to $\mathbb{N}$ to exploit the order there.

The simple method of just computing all the terms and waiting for all 1's won't work, because it will take on average $2^N$ steps to completion.

Induction won't help, because the optimal solution for $N$ sequences need have nothing at all to do with the optimal solution for $N+1$ sequences.